# How to remove the line under the logo in WooCommerce?

Tags: css, woocommerce

I'm trying to remove the line under the logo at: http://buyfireworks-shop.co.uk/product-category/roman-candles/ I can't remove the white border under the logo. I have tried various css to no avail.

Comment: The element ``<div id="theme-page-bg" class="master-holder-bg js-el">`` has a white top border. Can you remove that using css? (Yes, you can.)

Comment: Sorry, appears the element to override is ``<header id="mk-header-1" class="mk-header header-style-1 header-align-left toolbar-false menu-hover-5 sticky-style-false mk-background-stretch boxed-header"...``. Set its bottom-border to 0 and the white line is gone.

Comment: i see this is the code and even with it in my css it doesnt go. like I says it goes on every page other than the category pages.

Comment: and the other styles dont work. for examle the navigation is grey

Comment: Can you add the HTML/CSS right into your question for greater answering ease?

Comment: think I will just have to live with it. Visiting the site as below shows the issue

Comment: You are required to post your markup here, not a link to your website, which will change or go dead at any time: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Update this class in inline style sheet #4, you might need to do it in your page builder if you're using one, like Visual Composer or DiviBuilder if you can't find it in WooCommerce; from memory Woo doesn't have admin side styling accessible:

```
.mk-header { border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed; }
```

Remove the white border by setting border-bottom to none:

```
.mk-header { border-bottom: none; }
```

This style is being added with an inline stylesheet on the page, so you'll need to override it either with important or being really careful about specificity; making sure your .mk-header border fix is in the last css file after the WooCommerce stuff loads.

If you're still having trouble with WooCommerce styles you can [disable them entirely in functions.php](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/css-structure/)

```
// Remove each style one by one
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', 'jk_dequeue_styles' );
function jk_dequeue_styles( $enqueue_styles ) {
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-general'] );    // Remove the gloss
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-layout'] );     // Remove the layout
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-smallscreen'] );    // Remove the smallscreen optimisation
    return $enqueue_styles;
}

// Or just remove them all in one line
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: I have tried this but to no avail. I am using Jupiter theme. The pages where my settings seems to be overrode are product pages. For example, on the homepage and other pages, the navigation links are white, but when you are on a product page they revert to grey? strange and it is giving me a headache.

Comment: example: http://buyfireworks-shop.co.uk/product/alchemy/  renders fine but then if I click on the breadcrumb to go to totalfx it renders with the border again

Comment: Hi I think you need to clear your browser cache and try again. I'm not seeing the white underline anywhere on the site now.